# How to find an element of zipped list, that have a maximum value of division of its paired elements?

Tags: python, arrays, list, knapsack-problem

everyone!
I got stuck with such problem:
I created zipped list from two separated list, that I'm inputing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = list(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()))
    n, capacity = data[0:2]
    values = data[2:(2 * n + 2):2]
    weights = data[3:(2 * n + 2):2]
    ziplist = list(zip(values,weights))
    opt_value = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values)
```

So, as I typing

```
3 40
20 40
50 60
70 80
```

I got such list

```
[(20, 40), (50, 60), (70, 80)]
```

Now, I need to understand with element of this zipped list has a maximum value of division of each pair.

```
m = list(x/y for x,y in ziplist)
```

And the result is:

```
[0.5, 0.8333333333333334, 0.875]
```

So, it is evident, that I need to work with the last pair. But how should I code it properly? I want to avoid using extra list m somehow. In general I need to find index of zipped list -> then take from this element the value weight. So, my final output would be 80.

Also, I think that, I could go wrong way - because actually, I'm trying to solve fractional knapsack problem, so I'm trying to find the element with best ratio of it's weight and value.

Comment: you can do `max([x/y for x,y in ziplist])`

Comment: How did you get your division of integers to produce float results?

Comment: @ScottHunter That is the behavior of division in Python 3 (the `//` operator will produce integer results).

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of the greatest element of a list of numbers you can apply the following

```
argmax = max(enumerate(list_of_numbers), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

What this does is convert your list of numbers into a list of tuples of (index, value) pairs, and then select the pair whose second value is maximal. It then takes the first value from that pair (the index) and stores it in the variable `argmax`

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I wanted to answer. But I would directly write `... enumerate(x/y for x,y in ziplist) ...` to avoid creating a new named list in memory but directly use an unnamed generator.